# Alert dialog close button not functioning

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ember.js, zurb-foundation, ember-cli

I managed to get a foundation alert box (http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/alert_boxes.html) to show in my Ember CLI app. However, when I click the close icon (X), it doesnt actually close....

Any ideas?

I am doing this via a component. My code looks like:

**app/components/flash-message.js**

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  classNames:        ['alert-box'],
  classNameBindings: ['alertType'],

  attributeBindings: ['dataAlert:data-alert'],
  dataAlert: '',

  alertType: Ember.computed('type', function(){
    return this.get('type');
    // return 'alert-' + this.get('type');
  })
});
```

**app/templates/components/flash-message.hbs**

```
{{message}}
<a href="#" class="close">&times;</a>
```

**app/templates/application.hbs**

```
{{flash-message type='success' message='lorem ipsum'}}
```

The element is rendered exactly the same as the Zurb Foundation demo at http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/alert_boxes.html

```
<div id="ember717" class="ember-view alert-box success" data-alert="">
  lorem ipsum
  <a class="close" href="#">×</a>
</div>
```

I believe the same consequence happens with Twitter Bootstrap...

Comment: Have you javascript error in console ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you initiated foundation?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).foundation();
</script>
```